# AbstractMongoEventListener to identify update or add event spring boot mongoDb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to apply the auditing for update and delete operation using spring data MongoDB. For the add operation, I have the below model to find the addition in the database, which is working perfectly.

```
public class Audit {
    @CreatedBy
    private String CreatedBy;

    @CreatedDate
    private Instant createdDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedUser;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Instant lastModifiedDate;
}
```

How do I maintain the history for update and delete operation? I know there is a lifecycle hook for mongoDb in spring data

```
@Component
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class GenericAuditing extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Object> {
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenericAuditing.class);

    public GenericAuditing(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAfterSave(AfterSaveEvent<Object> event) {
        LOG.info("On After Save inserting the record to the Delete and update collection");
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onAfterDelete(AfterDeleteEvent<Object> event) {
        LOG.info("On After delete inserting the record to the Delete and update collection");
        Object obj = event.getSource();
        DeleteUpdateAudit deleteUpdateAudit = new DeleteUpdateAudit(obj, DatabaseAction.DELETE);
        this.mongoTemplate.insert(deleteUpdateAudit);
    }
}
```

How do I identify the onAfterSave is for Save or update. Since that method is called for both save and update operation. What is the best approach for auditing DELETE and UPDATE operation

Answer (score 1):

You can get from the event the creationTime and the lastUpdate. If the are equals, it's a save

```java
    @Override
    public void onAfterSave(AfterSaveEvent<User> event) {
        Date creationTime = event.getDocument().getDate("creationTime");
        Date lastUpdated = event.getDocument().getDate("lastUpdated");

        if (creationTime.equals(lastUpdated)) {
            // SAVE
        } else {
            // UPDATE
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With regard to identifying save or update, you could check the `Document` in the `AfterSaveEvent`. If it has an `_id` then it's an update:

```
    @Override
    public void onAfterSave(AfterSaveEvent<Object> event) {
        LOG.info("On After Save inserting the record to the Delete and update collection");
        
        boolean isUpdate = event.getDocument().containsKey("_id");
        if (isUpdate) {
            // add your specific update logic here
        } else {
            // add your specific insert logic
        }
    }
```